# All my f.select don't save my value when I create (but It work on edit), why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am annoyed because when I save for the first time my form (action to create), all of my `f.select` do not care about my choice. Indeed, when I'm in my show page or index page, I do not see any saved value.

I need to edit my form, choose in select again and save it again : tadam ! it work. It's stupid because I have to do it every two steps to make it work.

Do you have an idea why?

Here is an example code of one of my forms:

```
    <%= form.select(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories, :selected => form.object.category_id), {}, {required: 'true', class: 'form-control form-control-lg custom-select'}) %>
```

**UPDATE :**

```
def create
@event = Event.new(event_params)
@event.category_id = params[:category_id]

respond_to do |format|
  if @event.save
    format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

```
  def new
@event = Event.new
@categories = Category.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
@disable_nav = true
```

end

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: can you show your create action?

Comment: I do an update of my post. I'm not sure if it is that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <%=form.select :category_id, @categories, {}, {required: true, class: 'form-control form-control-lg custom-select'}%>
```

I  don't think you need to specify `:selected => form.object.category_id` with `f.select` as its fetches `category_id` of object `f` itself to select.

Edited answer:-
So far as i guessed at create action you will not get `params[:category_id]` but its `params[:event][:category_id]`

```
@event.category_id = params[:event][:category_id]
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I've got this error message : `undefined method 'name' for`. Just to notify my form use object `form` and not `f`, so I just change that of your solution.

Comment: PERFECT ! Thank you for your help. I understand now... that was a stupid mistake... sorry !

Comment: @SMIIILE Hi, check the updated answer, i think the issue is on your new page form_for is for `@event` object and so at your controller you will all form data which will be wrapped inside `event` key `{"event" => {"category_id" => "5"}` so you will have to  fetch category id like this: - `params[:event][:category_id]` also some changes made in `form.select`

Comment: Yes ! I saw that :) Thank you again Gabbar. You did my day!